# Trouble replicating CouchDB database to IBM Cloudant

Tags: couchdb, database-replication, cloudant

I'm trying to replicate a database from my local CouchDB installation to IBM Cloudant. I used curl for this, like this -

```
curl -X POST 'http://10.88.201.198:5984/_replicate' 
-d '{
        "source":"http://10.88.201.198:5984/temperature-db",
        "target":"username:password@username.cloudant.com/temperature-db"
    }' 
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-v
```

The attempt times out, and I get the following message -

```
 upload completely sent off: 255 out of 255 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
* Server CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/R16B03) is not blacklisted
< Server: CouchDB/1.6.1 (Erlang OTP/R16B03)
< Date: Wed, 27 Apr 2016 09:18:34 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 20
< Cache-Control: must-revalidate
< Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
< Connection: Keep-Alive
< 
{"error":"timeout"}
```

How do I go about fixing this ?

Comment: It looks like the couchdb instance running on 10.88.201.198 is unable to connect to your Cloudant instance. Are you able to connect to Cloudant from the machine at 10.88.201.198 either via the web or telnet (telnet username.cloudant.com 443)?

Comment: @MarkWatson yes I can access Cloudant using curl from `10.88.201.198`. I just queried a search index on Cloudant and got the proper results.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are your replication is taking a while to complete. To get around this you should use the `_replicator`database and you can monitor that at your leisure. There is documentation on the cloudant website on how to set up a replication using the `_replicator` database.

Comment: I cannot use Cloudant's `_replicator` as I do not have a public static IP for my local installation.

Comment: CouchDb also has the same feature. You'd use your Couchdb _replicator database see : http://couchdb.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.1/replication/replicator.html?h

Comment: I just tried it out. `_replication_state` is set to `error` and `_replication_state_reason` says `timeout`.

Comment: Try using http rather than https?

Comment: same result using http for both source and target

Answer (score 0):

you need add the user and password of some user who has permission to replicate and on target miss the 'https://' and use localhost or 0.0.0.0

```
curl -X POST 'http://username:password@localhost:5984/_replicate' 
-d '{
        "source":"http://username:password@localhost:5984/temperature-db",
        "target":"https://username:password@username.cloudant.com/temperature-db"
    }' 
-H "Content-Type: application/json"
-v
```

this maybe help

Comment: I do have permission to replicate, I tried to replicate to a CouchDB installation on another machine on my local network, and it worked.

Comment: dont forget the user and password of cloudant. and the https protocol.